# postgres, trigger to update json field with values from other columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres table with these columns:

```
"created_at" timestamp,
"modified_at" timestamp,
"data" jsonb
```

The timestamp fields are created at insert/update. I need a trigger to update also the `data` json column, adding those values at json root level.

I've tried this function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_dates()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
  NEW.data = jsonb_set(jsonb_set(NEW.data, '{modified_at}', to_jsonb(NEW.modified_at), true), '{created_at}', to_jsonb(NEW.created_at), true);
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$
```

and this trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER update_dates_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON stories
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION update_dates();
```

but nothings happens. How could i debug, i guess the error is the function?

Comment: "*I need to also adding those values at json root level*" - why? Avoid redundancies in your database storage. You can still add them when querying the data, is that not enough?

Comment: "*The timestamp fields are created at insert/update*" - by another trigger? If yes, does that trigger execute before or after the `update_dates_trigger`?

Comment: the timestamp fields are legacy, and are added within the insert/update query.

the json field is from a new application. I prefer to duplicate the data, because with a single query I can get the content of the json field and I give it back.

Comment: If you're going to modify inserted/updated values in a trigger you need to use `TRIGGER BEFORE`, otherwise modifications of the `NEW` record in a trigger function are ignored.

Comment: @GeorgeLivanoss you should define a `VIEW` on the table that returns the new JSON shape, instead of duplicating the stored data. You can still get the content with a single query then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments. My mistake was using `TRIGGER AFTER` and not `TRIGGER BEFORE`.

However i was convinced to not duplicate the data, so i decided to populate the values at query time:

````
SELECT jsonb_set(
         jsonb_set(data, '{modified_at}', 
                   CASE WHEN modified_at IS NULL THEN to_jsonb(current_timestamp)
                        ELSE to_jsonb(modified_at) END, true),
         '{created_at}', to_jsonb(created_at), true
       ) as data 
FROM table 
WHERE```
````

Comment: Btw, you can simplify this to `SELECT data || jsonb_build_object('modified_at', COALESCE(modified_at, current_timestamp), 'created_at', created_at) AS data`